# How to use Sub Function in R

Tags: regex, r

I am reading a csv file "`dopers`" in R.

```
dopers <- read.csv(file="generalDoping_alldata2.csv", head=TRUE,sep=",")
```

After reading the file, I have to do some data cleanup. For instance in the `country` column if it says

"United States" or "United State"

I would like to replace it with `"USA"`

I want to make sure that, if the word is `"  United States    "` or `"United   State   "`, even them my code should work. What I want to say is that even if there is any character before and after `"United States"` it is replaced with `"USA"`. I understand we can use `sub()` function for that purpose. I was looking online and found this, however I do not understand what `"^" "&" "*" "."` does. Can someone please explain.

```
dopers$Country = sub("^UNITED STATES.*$", "USA", dopers$Country)
```

Comment: `*` lets you have 0 or more of the preceding item; `+` is 1 or more; `.` matches anything (I think); `^` and `$` are the start and end of the vector you are looking in; and you can read `help('regex')` to see how to identify spaces. In fact, all of this is documented there.

Comment: @Frank why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @janos :) Laziness, I guess. And Karsten's answer is good, though I'd again emphasize reading `help('regex')` where such things as `[[:space:]]` are mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your examples,

```
s <- c(" United States", " United States ", "United States ")
```

You can define a regular expression pattern that matches them by

```
pat <- "^.*United State.*$"
```

Here, the `^` represents the beginning and `$` the end of the string, while
`.` stands for any character and `*` defines a repetition (zero to any). You can experiment with modified patterns, such as

```
pat <- "^[ ]*United State[ ]*$" # only ignores spaces
pat <- "^.*(United State|USA).*$" # only matches "  USA" etc.
```

The substitution is then performed by

```
gsub(pat, "USA", s)
```

Comment: nice and clear! +1. A question, will `"^.*(United State|USA).*$"` look for `United State` or `USA` in the middle of the string?

Comment: @ Karsten W. This really answers my question, however if I have spaces in between as well, then how can I handle that. I mean if in the data file it is written "United(spaces)States   ". I would appreciate if you can answer this.

Comment: @Michele Yes, because the `.*` pattern before and after `(United State|USA)` will match any other parts of the string.

Comment: @nasiajaffri Substitute in the same `[ ]*` pattern in the middle: `pat <- "^[ ]*United[ ]*State[ ]*$"`